# What's wrong with nullable columns in composite primary keys?

Tags: database, database-design

ORACLE does not permit NULL values in any of the columns that comprise a primary key. It appears that the same is true of most other "enterprise-level" systems.

At the same time, most systems also allow *unique* contraints on nullable columns.

Why is it that unique constraints can have NULLs but primary keys can not? Is there a fundamental logical reason for this, or is this more of a technical limitation?

Comment: [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733625/3404097)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Primary keys are for uniquely identifying rows. This is done by comparing all parts of a key to the input.

Per definition, NULL cannot be part of a successful comparison. Even a comparison to itself (`NULL = NULL`) will fail. This means a key containing NULL would not work.

Additonally, NULL is allowed in a foreign key, to mark an optional relationship.<sup>(*)</sup> Allowing it in the PK as well would break this.

---

<sup>(*)</sup>A word of caution: Having nullable foreign keys is not clean relational database design.

If there are two entities `A` and `B` where `A` can optionally be related to `B`, the clean solution is to create a resolution table (let's say `AB`). That table would link `A` with `B`: If there *is* a relationship then it would contain a record, if there *isn't* then it would not.

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one. Judging by the votes, this answer is the clearest to more people. I still feel that the answer by Tony Andrews explains the _intention_ behind this design better; do check it out as well!

Comment: Important to note that NULL should never be used to mark an optional relationship -- that is what FKs pointing in are for. This defeats the purpose of normalization right off the bat. Unfortunately it is difficult to trivially express parent-child relationships in most current RDBMSs, though, as few have a facility for a "bottom" value that is not NULL without the DBM defining a new type or inserting a dummy value to represent the top of the tree. Using NULL as "top" means it can't be used to indicate uncertainty. (related discussion for serious DB nerds: http://zxq9.com/archives/840)

Comment: @zxq9 That's what I meant by "NULL is allowed in a foreign key", I thought that would be clear.

Comment: Q: When do you want a NULL FK instead of a lack of a row? A: Only in a version of a schema denormalized for optimization. In non-trivial schemas unnormalized issues like this can cause problems whenever new features are required. otoh, the web design crowd doesn't care. I would at least add a note of caution about this instead of making it sound like a good design idea.

Comment: You are right, in a properly normalized database there would be a resolution table that links B to A, not a nullable FK in A. I'll add a cautionary note.

Comment: "Having nullable foreign keys is not clean relational database design." - a null-free database design (Sixth normal form) invariably adds complexity, the space-savings gained are often outweighed by the extra programmer work needed to realise those gains.

Comment: what if it's an ABC resolution table ? with optional C

Comment: The ANSI standard is to not allow null columns as a part of the primary key.  The question calls out Oracle specifically but does mention that most other enterprise level databases have the same restriction.  Since this is the accepted answer it should probably include this as the reason why most databases follow the convention.

Comment: I tried to avoid to write "because the standard forbids it", as this really explains nothing.

Comment: An SQL FK can reference nullable UNIQUE columns. And one needn't declare PKs or UNIQUE NOT NULL to use the DB.  We can also use a subrow with NULL to identify a row as long as there is no other row that IS NOT DISTINCT FROM it. The point of declaring a column set PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL is  there's no *declarative* SQL way to enforce 1. such an IS NOT DISTINCT FROM constraint & 2. that a subrow elsewhere IS NOT DISTINCT FROM some subrow under those columns--since any FK subrow with NULL satisfies a FK constraint. *PKs give declaratively enforced identification--given other language choices*.

Answer (score 72):

A primary key defines a unique identifier for **every** row in a table: when a table has a primary key, you have a guranteed way to select any row from it.

A unique constraint does not necessarily identify every row; it just specifies that **if** a row has values in its columns, **then** they must be unique.  This is not sufficient to uniquely identify **every** row, which is what a primary key must do.

Comment: In Sql Server a unique constraint that has a nullable column, allows the value 'null' in that column only once (given identical values for the other columns of the constraint). So such a unique constraint essentially behaves like a pk with a nullable column.

Comment: I confirm the same for Oracle (11.2)

Comment: In Oracle (I don't know about SQL Server), the table can contain many rows where **all** the columns in a unique constraint are null.  However, if some column(s) in the unique constraint are not null and some are null then uniqueness is enforced.

Comment: How does this apply to composite UNIQUE?

Comment: @Dims As with nearly anything else in SQL databases "it depends on the implementation". In most dbs a "primary key" is actually a UNIQUE constraint underneath. The idea of "primary key" is not really any more special or powerful than the concept of UNIQUE. The real difference is that if you have two independent aspects of a table that can be guaranteed UNIQUE then you don't have a normalized database by definition (you're storing two types of data in the same table).

Comment: SQL PK is UNIQUE NOT NULL. But SQL Server UNIQUE, which allows at most one subrow with a NULL in a given column, is not standard SQL UNIQUE, which allows any number of subrows with NULL in any column. (Which is not everyday/math unique, treating NULL as just another value, which is SQL IS DISTINCT FROM all other subrows).

Comment: PostgreSQL behavior for unique constraints: "... [T]wo null values are never considered equal in this comparison. That means even in the presence of a unique constraint it is possible to store duplicate rows that contain a null value in at least one of the constrained columns. This behavior conforms to the SQL standard, but we have heard that other SQL databases might not follow this rule. So be careful when developing applications that are intended to be portable." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-constraints.html

Answer (score 55):

Fundamentally speaking nothing is wrong with a NULL in a multi-column primary key. But having one has implications the designer likely did not intend, which is why many systems throw an error when you try this.

Consider the case of module/package versions stored as a series of fields:

```
CREATE TABLE module
  (name        varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
   description text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE version
  (module      varchar(20) REFERENCES module,
   major       integer NOT NULL,
   minor       integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   patch       integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   release     integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
   ext         varchar(20),
   notes       text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (module, major, minor, patch, release, ext));
```

The first 5 elements of the primary key are regularly defined parts of a release version, but some packages have a customized extension that is usually not an integer (like "rc-foo" or "vanilla" or "beta" or whatever else someone for whom *four* fields is insufficient might dream up). If a package does not have an extension, then it is NULL in the above model, and no harm would be done by leaving things that way.

But what *is* a NULL? It is supposed to represent a *lack* of information, an unknown. That said, perhaps this makes more sense:

```
CREATE TABLE version
  (module      varchar(20) REFERENCES module,
   major       integer NOT NULL,
   minor       integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   patch       integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   release     integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
   ext         varchar(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
   notes       text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (module, major, minor, patch, release, ext));
```

In this version the "ext" part of the tuple is NOT NULL but defaults to an empty string -- which is semantically (and practically) different from a NULL. A NULL is an unknown, whereas an empty string is a deliberate record of "something not being present". In other words, "empty" and "null" are different things. Its the difference between "I don't have a value here" and "I don't know what the value here is."

When you register a package that lacks a version extension you *know* it lacks an extension, so an empty string is actually the correct value. A NULL would only be correct if you didn't know whether it had an extension or not, or you knew that it did but didn't know what it was. This situation is easier to deal with in systems where string values are the norm, because there is no way to represent an "empty integer" other than inserting 0 or 1, which will wind up being rolled up in any comparisons made later (which has its own implications)*.

Incidentally, both ways are valid in Postgres (since we're discussing "enterprise" RDMBSs), but comparison results can vary quite a bit when you throw a NULL into the mix -- because NULL == "don't know" so all results of a comparison involving a NULL wind up being NULL since you can't know something that is unknown. **DANGER!** Think carefully about that: this means that NULL comparison results *propagate* through a series of comparisons. This can be a source of subtle bugs when sorting, comparing, etc.

Postgres assumes you're an adult and can make this decision for yourself. Oracle and DB2 assume you didn't realize you were doing something silly and throw an error. This is *usually* the right thing, but not always -- you might *actually* not know and have a NULL in some cases and therefore leaving a row with an unknown element against which meaningful comparisons are impossible is correct behavior.

In any case you should strive to eliminate the number of NULL fields you permit across the entire schema and doubly so when it comes to fields that are part of a primary key. In the vast majority of cases the presence of NULL columns is an indication of un-normalized (as opposed to deliberately de-normalized) schema design and should be thought very hard about before being accepted.

[* *NOTE: It is possible to create a custom type that is the union of integers and a "bottom" type that would semantically mean "empty" as opposed to "unknown". Unfortunately this introduces a bit of complexity in comparison operations and usually being truly type correct isn't worth the effort in practice as you shouldn't be permitted many `NULL` values at all in the first place. That said, it would be wonderful if RDBMSs would include a default `BOTTOM` type in addition to `NULL` to prevent the habit of casually conflating the semantics of "no value" with "unknown value".*]

Comment: This is a VERY NICE answer and explains a lot about NULL values and it's implications through many situations. You, sir, have now my respect! Not even in college I got such a good explanation over NULL values inside databases. Thank you!

Comment: I support the main idea of this answer. But writing like 'supposed to represent a lack of information, an unknown', 'semantically (and practically) different from a NULL', 'A NULL is an unknown', 'an empty string is a deliberate record of "something not being present"', 'NULL == "don't know"', etc are vague & misleading & really only mnemonics for absent statements re how NULL or any value is or can or was intended to be used--per the rest of the post. (Including  in inspiring the (bad) design of SQL NULL features.) They don't justify or explain anything; they should be explained & debunked.

Answer (score 21):

NULL == NULL -> false (at least in DBMSs)

So you wouldn't be able to retrieve any relationships using a NULL value even with additional columns with real values.

Comment: This sounds like the best answer, but I still don't understand why this is prohibited upon primary key creation.  If this was just a retrieval problem, you could use `where pk_1 = 'a' and pk_2 = 'b'` with normal values, and switch to `where pk_1 is null and pk_2 = 'b'` when there are nulls.

Comment: Or even more reliably, `where (a.pk1 = b.pk1 or (a.pk1 is null and b.pk1 is null)) and (a.pk2 = b.pk2 or (a.pk2 is null and b.pk2 is null))`/

Comment: Wrong answer.  NULL==NULL -> UNKNOWN. Not false.  The catch is that a constraint is not considered violated if the outcome of the test is UNKNOWN.  This often makes it _SEEM_ as if the comparison yields false, but it really doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

I still believe this is a fundamental / functional flaw brought about by a technicality. If you have an optional field by which you can identify a customer you now have to hack a dummy value into it, just because NULL != NULL, not particularly elegant yet it is an "industry standard"

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Tony Andrews is a decent one. But the real answer is that this has been a convention used by relational database community and is NOT a necessity. Maybe it is a good convention, maybe not.

Comparing anything to NULL results in UNKNOWN (3rd truth value).
So as has been suggested with nulls all traditional wisdom concerning equality goes out the window. Well that's how it seems at first glance.

But I don't think this is necessarily so and even SQL databases don't think that NULL destroys all possibility for comparison.

Run in your database the query
SELECT * FROM VALUES(NULL)
UNION
SELECT * FROM VALUES(NULL)

What you see is just one tuple with one attribute that has the value NULL.
So the union recognized here the two NULL values as equal.

When comparing a composite key that has 3 components to a tuple with 3 attributes (1, 3, NULL) = (1, 3, NULL) <=> 1 = 1 AND 3 = 3 AND NULL = NULL
The result of this is UNKNOWN.

But we could define a new kind of comparison operator eg. ==.
X == Y <=> X = Y OR (X IS NULL AND Y IS NULL)

Having this kind of equality operator would make composite keys with null components or non-composite key with null value unproblematic.

Comment: No, the UNION has recognized the two NULLs as non-distinct.  Which is not the same thing as "equal".  Try UNION ALL instead and you'll get two rows.  And as for the "new kind of comparison operator", SQL already has it.  IS NOT DISTINCT FROM.  But that by itself is not sufficient.  Using this in SQL constructs such as NATURAL JOIN, or the REFERENCES clause of a foreign key, will require yet additional options on those constructs.

Comment: Aha, Erwin Smout.
Truly a pleasure to meet you also on this forum!
I was not aware of SQL's "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM".
Very interesting!
But it seems that it is exactly what I meant with my made-up == operator.

Could you explain me why you say that: "that by itself is not sufficient" ?

Comment: The REFERENCES clause builds on equality, by definition.  A kind of REFERENCES that matches a child tuple/row with a parent tuple/row, based on the corresponding attribute values being NOT DISTINCT instead of (the stricter) EQUAL, would require the ability to specify this option, but the syntax doesn't allow it.  Ditto for NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: In order for a foreign key to work the refered must be unique (ie. all values must be distinct). Which means that it could have a single null value. All the null values could then refer to that single null if the REFERENCES would be defined with the NOT DISTINCT operator.

I think that would be better (in the sense of more useful).

With JOINs (both outer and inner) I think the strict equals is better because the "NULL MATCHES" would multiply when nulls on the left side would match all nulls on the right side.