# Entity Framework: field of composite key cannot be nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a model with composite key - the row is the key:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

Running the code below it throws an exception `DbEntityValidationException` with message: `The Date field is required.`:

```
var it = new Item { Date = null, UserId = 2 };
m_Entities.Items.Add(it);
m_Entities.SaveChanges(); // throws exception
```

(`m_Entities` is usual `DbContext` descendant with Items defined as `DbSet<Item>`)
Why is the `Date` required if it can be `null` (declared as `DateTime?`) ? And how to allow `null` to be a valid value for `Date`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answer from Raphael lead me to another search. Here is the why it is not possible (answer from Cobsy):

[What's wrong with nullable columns in composite primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386040/whats-wrong-with-nullable-columns-in-composite-primary-keys)

In short:
`NULL == NULL` -> false

Wierd. The solution for me is to add Id column into Model.

BTW: MySQL allow me not to define Primary Key, then I'm allowed to have such schema - EF complains about not defining the key :-(.

Comment: Actually "NULL == NULL" isn't false, it's NULL, but I agree it's not true.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible with Sql Server, or Oracle for any part of a primary key.

But you can have a unique constraint on these datas.

Which means you can have one time

```
UserId = 2, Date = null
```

Then

```
UserId = 2, Date = <NOT NULL>
```

You can't create directly unique constraints with Code First, but look at SMO.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Every RDBMS requirement is, that primary key must be not nullable.

Comment: Well, the primary key is {UserId, Date} where it is ensured that only Date is nullable - so why it is not possible? Do not agree with your statement. Still, the code is kind of port from PHP/MySQL where it was possible...