# Entity Framework Composite primary key when one of them is an identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a composite key mapped in a class as shown:

```
HasKey(l => new { l.A, l.B });
```

But, here A is supposed to be an identity.

```
Property(l => l.A).HasColumnName("A").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
Property(l => l.B).HasColumnName("B");
```

However, when I try to Add an object with the value of A(null since it is an identity) and B, I get a Primary Key violation.

Is there any way to get around this?

The types are as follows:

```
public Int64? A{ get; set; } //Identity
public int B { get; set; }
```

And from a DB world:

```
A   bigint
B   int
```

Comment: What type are A and B?

Comment: Why do you need `B` in the primary key?  Why is the identity column not sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where the Key field is an Integer, Code First defaults to
`DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, so, `A` and `B` are Identity by default. You need to specify `B` is not Identity. Try with this configuration:

```
Property(l => l.A).HasColumnName("A");
Property(l => l.B).HasColumnName("B").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

BTW, why `A` is nullable?. A PK defines a unique identifier for every row in a table, so, due to A is Identity, you always going to have a value in that column when you insert a new row in your table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not allowed to have null values even in composite primary keys. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888723/337294), the workaround would be to define a separated Id column as primary key.