# Entity Framework error with MySql Provider

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I'm creating a Web api project on my Visual Studio Professional 2013.
I would like to use EntityFramework to get data from a MySql Database.
To do so, I followed the following steps:

- Installed the .NET Connector for MySQL.
- Created a Web Api project.
- Installed Entity Framework via Nuget
- Installed the Mysql Data provider via Nuget

In order to use Entity Framework, I wanted to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.
The system found the connector and I'm able to create a connexion with my MySQL Database. The trageted database is also found and I'm about to add the databases' objects that I need in my ADO.NET Data Model.
Here comes the error. When I'm trying to add a table which contains by default null value in some columns, the table is not added and errors are displayed saying the following:
**ERROR 13101: the component key 'name of the column' of the type 'name of the table' is not valid. Any component of the key can accept null value.**

Here is the script that I use to create the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `ps_address` (
  `id_address` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_country` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_state` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_customer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_manufacturer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_supplier` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_warehouse` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `alias` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(128)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(12)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `other` text,
  `phone` varchar(32)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_mobile` varchar(32)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dni` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_address`),
  KEY `address_customer` (`id_customer`),
  KEY `id_country` (`id_country`),
  KEY `id_state` (`id_state`),
  KEY `id_manufacturer` (`id_manufacturer`),
  KEY `id_supplier` (`id_supplier`),
  KEY `id_warehouse` (`id_warehouse`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is this a recurrent problem ? Maybe somebody has faced that issue before ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are parts of your key nullable on said table? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888087/entity-framework-field-of-composite-key-cannot-be-nullable

Comment: what do you mean ? Some columns are nullable and this is the origin of the problem...

Comment: What he is saying is that you can't have a composite key that can potentially contain NULL values. Specify a PK for the table that cannot have NULL values.