# Error: The seed entity for entity type 'JobAccessLevel' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'PersonId'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm getting the following error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'JobAccessLevel' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'PersonId'.

And this seems to be caused by trying to seed the database with PersonId = null.
(but that is exactly what i want to do)

How can i fix this issue?

**Context to my problem:**

Lets imagine I want to secure something based on PersonId and the persons job, but i want to have a generic Access lever for a specific Job, but specific Access levels for a Person in a given job.

To control this I've created the following entity to be stored in the database:

```
public class JobAccessLevel
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public int AccessLevelId { get; set; }
    public AccessLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }
}
```

So when the PersonId is null I can still use the access level.

The configuration file to create this entity in the database is like this:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobAccessLevel> builder)
{
    builder.Property(JobAccessLevel=> JobAccessLevel.JobId ).ValueGeneratedNever();
    builder.Property(JobAccessLevel=> JobAccessLevel.PersonId ).ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder.HasKey(JobAccessLevel=> new { JobAccessLevel.JobId , JobAccessLevel.PersonId });


    builder.HasData(new List<JobAccessLevel>
    {
        new JobAccessLevel
        {
            JobId = 1,
            AccessLevel= 2,
            PersonId = null
        },
        new JobAccessLevel
        {
            JobId = 2,
            AccessLevel= 1,
            PersonId = null
        },
        new JobAccessLevel
        {
            JobId = 2,
            AccessLevel= 2,
            PersonId = 3
        }
    });
}
```

p.s: I get this error when trying to create a new migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you define the key to be a composite key of `JobId` and `PersonId`, which requires both to have a value. See also:

- [Entity Framework: field of composite key cannot be nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888087/entity-framework-field-of-composite-key-cannot-be-nullable)
- [What's wrong with nullable columns in composite primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386040/whats-wrong-with-nullable-columns-in-composite-primary-keys)

You probably want the entity to have its own id:

```
public class JobAccessLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And then:

```
builder.HasKey(a => new { a.Id });
```

Which you then also have to provide in your seed data:

```
builder.HasData(new List<JobAccessLevel>
{
    new JobAccessLevel
    {
        Id = 1,
        JobId = 1,
        AccessLevel= 2,
        PersonId = null
    },
    // ...
```