# Change Varchar data type to primary key

Tags: mysql

Hello i am curently trying to set up a data base in MYSQL and i want to have my Varchar element as the Primary Key but it always gives me an error like this:

`Invalid use of NULL value`

the command i am using is:

```
ALTER  TABLE temp_keys ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_key);
```

and here is how the table is set up:

[Intel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ3s2.png)

I hope that some one of you can help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NULL value in multi-column primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001333/null-value-in-multi-column-primary-key)

Comment: Also PRIMARY KEY

A unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR` data type is not a problem. **PRIMARY KEY** columns must be defined as NOT NULL. Append `CHANGE temp_key temp_key VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL` in your query and change value(50) according to your need.

Just execute `ALTER TABLE temp_keys  CHANGE temp_key temp_key VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,  ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_key);`
[image: result]